# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xca' in file /usr/local/bin/python3 on line 2, but no encoding declared

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, utf

I am trying to schedule a crontab job to run a python script and referring to python in /usr/local/bin/python3 but getting this error

SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xca' in file /usr/local/bin/python3 on line 2

What does this mean and how can I solve it? I can't open the python3 file

Comment: What's the command you're trying to run?

Comment: * * * * * /Users/name/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/name/Desktop/Scrape/scraper.py

Comment: It means your source file isn’t saved in the UTF-8 encoding and you didn’t declare the actual encoding.

Comment: Please strip unnecessary info, it should be clear whether the execution with cron is part of the problem or if it also happens without. Also, where exactly did you make what precise observations (i.e. where does the error from the title come from)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're calling to python twice. Decide which interpreter you want to use and run either:

```
* * * * * /Users/name/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python /Users/name/Desktop/Scrape/scraper.py
```

or

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/name/Desktop/Scrape/scraper.py
```

Comment: @Okay did you try? did it work?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, it did solve this specific error but I started obtaining a new error (something regarding unable to import required dependencies: Numpy)

Comment: @Okay you can thank me by upvoting & accepting this answer :) I would love to help in another question, please open a new question and share a link